# Project migration to Webpack2 errors

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-2

I made this more specific question about a Webpack2 migration from Webpack1.

The PR can be consulted here : https://github.com/patrickheng/vuejs-webpack-boilerplate/pull/3

I still got errors when I launch npm start.

It looks like related to 2 issues:

1. webpack-hot-middleware incorrect path issue
2. stage-0 (ES2015 experimental) babel transpile since Webpack2 migration asked to remove transpilation from the migration guide

   ```
   {
     test: /\.js$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loader: 'babel-loader',
     options: {
       "presets": [["es2015", {"modules": false}]]
     },
   },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`::` is a more recent ECMAScript feature. You need to use stage-0 for this. There is no need to remove transpilation with webpack 2. For the other JS errors, it seems like your presets doesn't work. You can try doing this:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    babelrc: false,
    presets: [[{ "es2015": { "modules": false } }], "stage-0"]
  },
},
```

Note the `babelrc: false`, this will avoid loading the presets from a `.babelrc` file.